# The SMTP server did not verify that a secure connection was run or taken. Authentication Required

Tags: smtp, gmail, sendmail, smtp-auth

I'm trying to send mail to my Gmail account, but every time I get an authentication failed error. How can I solve it?

```
public static void send_Click(string test, string aa)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        mm.From = new MailAddress("gulerbusra1998@gmail.com");
        mm.To.Add("gulerbusra1998@gmail.com");
        mm.Subject = "testt";
        mm.Body = "testt";
        sc.Port = 587;
        sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("gulerbusra1998@gmail.com", "eedfcdefe");
        sc.EnableSsl = true;
        sc.Send(mm);
        MessageBox.Show("Email has meen sent.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```